# Compute $f'(t)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-tx^2}\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration

For :$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt{\pi}$

Compute $f'(t)=\left(\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-tx^2}\mathrm dx\right)'$. With$t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply evaluate directly.  By scaling, you can easily obtain

$$f(t) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{t}} = \sqrt{\pi} t^{-1/2}$$

so that

$$f'(t) = -\frac12 \sqrt{\pi} t^{-3/2}$$

**EDIT**

I see that the problem statement is confusing; in this case where $f'$ is the integral, $f'(t) = \sqrt{\pi} t^{-1/2}$.  Then

$$f(t) = 2 \sqrt{\pi t} + C$$

where $C$ is a constant of integration.

Comment: The problem says that $t\in\mathbb R$, but you take $t>0$?  The problem says that $f'(t)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-tx^2}dx$, but you take $f(t)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-tx^2}dx$?

Comment: The problem statement is confusing; I cover either case.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Use differentiation under the integral sign (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign).

Answer (score 0):

Going with what Ngua suggested, for t>0 $f'(t)$ will simply be equal to $\frac{\sqrt\pi}{\sqrt{t}}$.You can also check it on wolfram alpha.